Alternatives to Running DBCC CHECKDB on a Production Database
I am currently running DBCC CHECKDB on one of my production databases, but it is taking a very long time and affecting the server performance. I am looking for alternatives or best practices to minimize the impact on the production environment.
Here are a few solutions I've come across:

Run DBCC CHECKDB at night when the server has less load.
Run DBCC CHECKDB with the PHYSICAL_ONLY option to reduce the scope of checks and speed up the process.
Create a copy of the database on a separate server and run DBCC CHECKDB there.

I would appreciate any advice or additional recommendations from the community to effectively manage this process without impacting the production database performance.
